# Grid layout with expanded item and items around it

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

Trying to create layout that looks like this:

[image: desired layout]

Each item is a square (created via padding-bottom technique). Items should not overlap.

I'm having trouble with green element, no matter what `grid-area` prop I apply – it creates blank space on left side.

I made a demo on JSFiddle – http://jsfiddle.net/f2to1kyw/

Is it even possible to create such layout without JS?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100%;
}

.item:before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.item--big {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}

.item--green {
  background: #36926A
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--big"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item item--green"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it even possible to create such layout without JS?

Yes. There are a number of ways of doing this with CSS Grid.

### Using the `grid-area` property:

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area):

> The `grid-area` CSS property is a shorthand property for `grid-row-start`,
>   `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end` and `grid-column-end`…

So the value of the `grid-area` property for the green box would be: `2 / 4 / 4 / 6`

which is shorthand for:

```css
grid-row-start: 2;
grid-column-start: 4;
grid-row-end: 4;
grid-column-end: 6;
```

so the CSS rule would be:

```css
.item--green {
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 4 / 6;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100%;
}

.item:before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.item--big {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}

.item--green {
  background: #36926A;
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 4 / 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--big"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item item--green"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

### Using the `grid-column` / `grid-row` properties

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100%;
}

.item:before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.item--big {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.item--green {
  background: #36926A;
  grid-column: 4 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item item--big"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item item--green"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

The Relevant Code:

```css
.item--green {
  grid-column: 4 / span 2; /* start at column 4 and span 2 columns  */
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;  /* start at row 2 and span 2 rows */
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, I  was looking wrong way. It seems you can do the same if you use "auto" instead of 4 & 2, right? "auto / auto / span 2 / span 2"

Comment: @Marvin3 - like I said, there are plenty of possible ways to do this, do whatever makes the most sense to you :) (personally I prefer using grid-row and grid-column properties in order not to confuse the rows with the columns)